# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Number' at row 1 - JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

I keep getting this error when I am trying to insert these values. Earlier posts containing this error doesn't help me. I have other classes/db with same query but with 3 values(varchar,varchar,int) and they work. This is my query:

```
String sql = ("INSERT INTO `PlayerTable`(`Name`, `Lastname`, `Number`, `Points`, `Assists`, `Rebounds`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        PreparedStatement ps = PlayerBase.get().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, playerNameFld.getText());
        ps.setString(2, playerLNFld.getText());
        ps.setString(3, playerNumberFld.getText());
        ps.setString(4, playerPointsFld.getText());
        ps.setString(5, playerAssistsFld.getText());
        ps.setString(6, playerReboundsFld.getText());
        ps.execute();
```

and this is my db class:

```
public class PlayerBase {

private static Connection connection;

// Pravi konekciju za igraca
private static Connection createConnection() {
    try {
        // Pristupa drajveru u JAR fajlu
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/player", "root", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static Connection get() {
    if (connection == null) {
        connection = createConnection();
    }
    return connection;
}

public static ResultSet query(String sql) {
    try {
        Connection connection = get();
        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
        return s.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the whole stactrace please and the table structure?

Comment: Why are you using `setString()` for a number?

Comment: What datatype `Number` column accepts?

Comment: Also, update your question with error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this line of code:

```
ps.setString(3, playerNumberFld.getText());
```

You are calling `setString` instead `setInt`

So to fix it call:

```
ps.setInt(3, Integer.valueOf(playerNumberFld.getText()));
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and now I am getting _NumberFormatException: For input string: ""_ error. Number column expects int.

Comment: Which means, you have to pass SOME value. Empty value from JTextField/TextField will give you a NumberFormatException. Put some kind of filter like `if(playerNumberFld.getText().trim().length() != 0) {...}`

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it with validation check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Number column expects something that can be interpreted as a number, but your playerNumberFld.getText does not conform to this expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Error is generating due to two reason

**ps.setString(3,playerNumberFId.getText())**

1st reason
you are invoking **setString** instead of **setInt**

2nd reason(may be)

**playerFId.getText()** return string value, so you have need to convert into int format
using **Integer.parseInt(...)** method